# How to avoid overlapping of path on android?

Tags: android, path, overlapping

I'd like to draw multiple gradient paths.
(I must use individual gradient for each path.)

However, each path overlapped to the other.

How to be avoid (clear) overlapping and draw natural paths?

(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR is not working :<)

Please help!

code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class AnimatingLineView extends View {
private Paint paint;
private Path path;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public AnimatingLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
        int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initLinewView();
}

public AnimatingLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initLinewView();
}

public AnimatingLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initLinewView();
}

public AnimatingLineView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initLinewView();
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    PorterDuffXfermode xfermode  = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(337, 658);
    path.lineTo(324, 643);
    path.lineTo(312, 625);
    path.lineTo(301, 606);
    path.lineTo(289, 588);

    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(337, 658, 289, 588,
            Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255), Color.argb(70, 255, 255, 255), TileMode.CLAMP));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(289, 588);
    path.lineTo(279, 564);
    path.lineTo(273, 514);
    path.lineTo(273, 518);
    path.lineTo(274, 495);

    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(289, 588, 274, 495,
            Color.argb(70, 255, 255, 255), Color.argb(140, 255, 255, 255), TileMode.CLAMP));        
    paint.setXfermode(xfermode);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(274, 495);
    path.lineTo(272, 471);
    path.lineTo(272, 447);
    path.lineTo(277, 423);
    path.lineTo(278, 401);

    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(274, 495, 278, 401,
            Color.argb(140, 255, 255, 255), Color.argb(70, 255, 255, 255), TileMode.CLAMP));
    paint.setXfermode(xfermode);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(278, 401);
    path.lineTo(278, 385);
    path.lineTo(278, 370);
    path.lineTo(278, 355);
    path.lineTo(278, 340);

    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(278, 401, 278, 340,
            Color.argb(70, 255, 255, 255), Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255), TileMode.CLAMP));
    paint.setXfermode(xfermode);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

private void initLinewView() {
    path= new Path();
    paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(28);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}
}
```

Comment: PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR should work, could you show what you tried with it? Also you may want to look into constructor chaining to make your life easier.

Comment: Dear. Johan. You can see what I did with PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR above code. I tried to use CLEAR whenever drawing the next path. Without gradient shader, CLEAR works. With gradient shader, CLEAR doesn't work...